# MySQL Join two tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in my database, customers, sales, and tires. What I am trying to do is write a script to display all tire manufacturers and the revenue each generates through the sale of tires.

This is the script I have although it's not executing.

```
SELECT Manufacturer AS "Tire Maker", (UnitPrice) AS "Sales Figures"
FROM Tire JOIN Sales
ON Tire.TireID=Sales.TireID
GROUP BY Manufacturer ASC;
```

Comment: Do you get an error when this script executes or just no results?

Comment: What's the error? Or please post the tables so we can join them.

Comment: Is there a way I can post screen shots? I'm not getting an error I just can't get all the manufacturers to query

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the unit price. Otherwise, you'll just return one entry of the sales figures rather than the sum of them for the manufacturer.

The Join looked fine, but I did change it to a left join.  The Group by had ASC after it which should've given an error.  It seemed like you wanted the Group by of Manufacturer, but then needed Order by of Manufacturer in order to put the results in the order you wanted.

```
SELECT 
    `Manufacturer` AS `Tire Maker`
    , SUM(`UnitPrice`) AS `Sales Figures`
FROM 
    `Tire` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `Sales`
ON 
    `Tire`.`TireID` = `Sales`.`TireID`
GROUP BY 
    `Manufacturer`
ORDER BY
    `Manufacturer` ASC;
```

Comment: I have 9 tire manufactures and now it's only querying 6 of them